# Accidentally removed all commands in terminal

Tags: mac, terminal

I was following a tutorial and put in the following line:

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin/"
```

Now no commands work at all, not even things like `ls`.

What does the command do that I copy and pasted in and how do I fix it?

Comment: What happens when You open new Terminal window?

Comment: Oh crikey that actually fixes it. Panicked a bit when nothing was working. If you give that as an answer i'll happily accept :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## What you did

`$PATH` is the variable that tells your shell (bash by default) where to look for your commands. It contains a list of directories, separated with colons (`:`). When you type `ls`, the shell will search all the directories listed within `$PATH` (`/bin`, `/usr/bin`, and so on) until it finds a file called `ls`, and will execute that.

Normally, you set a variable simply with

```
variable="foo bar baz"
```

...however, that only sets that variable for the current shell -- those changes won't carry over to subshells, which can be important in (for example) scripts. Using

```
export variable="foo bar baz"
```

...*will* allow you to use the variable in subshells.

So, when you use `export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin/"`, you are overwriting the `$PATH` variable -- so when you try to use `ls`, the shell looks in `~/.composer/vendor/bin/`, doesn't find any file named `ls`, and so fails. What you probably want to do is *add* `~/.composer/vendor/bin/` to your `$PATH`, which you can do with:

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin/"
```

You can view the current contents of your `$PATH` with `echo $PATH`.

## How to fix it

All of this only applies to the current shell (and all its subshells, since you used `export`), so you can fix the problem most simply by opening a new terminal, as [Mateusz Szlosek's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/146941) notes.

If you *do* want to alter your $PATH permanently, you can put that line at the end of your `~/.bashrc`, which is sourced whenever you open an interactive shell. This is standard practice if you want to write a few of your own scripts (on Linux, we use `~/bin` for user scripts, but they can go anywhere).

Comment: Fantastic answer and thanks alot for explaining. Really need to get out of the habit of copy and pasting things from tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

`export` command works in the current session only. You can "fix" it by opening new **Terminal** window/tab.

Comment: If you want to change the path for the current session, use `export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin/:$PATH"` instead, this will keep the existing PATH entries.