# Terminal not recognising commands

Tags: bash

I have tried to add TextWrangler to the path environment modifying the file `.bash_profile`. This is what I have added:

```
# Just a comment 
PATH=/Applications/TextWrangler.app/Contents/MacOS
export PATH
```

I am not sure if it was exactly like this, but I am sure it was not so different. I must admit I do not know exactly what I was doing with the commands above, but by suggestions of other people and content on the web, I decided to add it to the .bash_profile file.

Now, when I type for example `ls` or `open` or `nano` it does not work. I have seen on the web that this has already happened to other people.

I am not able to open the .bash_profile file with TextWrangler to restore it as it was, so this is a big problem, I might say.

Comment: Is that the only thing in .bash_profile - also what happens when you try to edit the file? (The obvious thing to do is restore .bash_profile from a backup - if no backup set up Time Machine or anther backup before doing anything else

Comment: Here's similar question about wrong `PATH` export: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146940/accidentally-removed-all-commands-in-terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can modify the .bash_profile with textedit or textmate? You can download textmate from http://www.macromates.com/download. I like it a lot better than TextWrangler.

Comment: I don't think so. I use TextMate 2.0 alpha which is free, but it looks you can purchase other versions.

Comment: Also, TextMate 2 is open source and on GitHub: [textmate/textmate](https://github.com/textmate/textmate). I've been using it (the alpha) as my main editor for a while and haven't noticed any stability issues.